# Expected ')' before 'or'

Tags: c

I have the following code,

```
int count_div ( int A, int B, int K ) {
   float div =(float) (B - A) / K;
  if ((A % K == 0 ) or (B % K == 0))
    return div + 1;
  return div;
}
```

I am getting the error,

```
func.c:3: error: expected ')' before 'or'
```

Now I don't think there is any need of another bracket before that. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Have you included `iso646.h` to enable `or`?

Comment: @Jon: That's new to me. What's `iso646.h`?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the `and` and `or` "keywords" in C, you must include the `<iso646.h>` header. (But you should probably just use `||`; it's more familiar to most readers who know C.)

Answer (score 1):

try replacing 'or' with '||'  the or operator

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((A % K == 0 ) or (B % K == 0))
```

in [c](/questions/tagged/c) there is no keyword `or`, you should use `||`:

```
if ((A % K == 0 ) || (B % K == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't the number of parens.  In almost all languages (or at least the ones I've used) the statement:

if ((A % K == 0 ) or (B % K == 0))

should be written as:

if ((A % K == 0 ) || (B % K == 0))

Comment: A lot of languages do use `or` instead of `||`; C (by default) isn't one of them, though.

Comment: Good to know, I figured that would be true which is why I qualified it :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no "or" operator in C. Try || instead of "or".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (but not recommended),

```
#define or ||
#define and &&

...
if ((A % K == 0 ) or (B % K == 0))
...
```

I don't recommend it because it's really non-standard.

Comment: Those macros, and several others, are defined in the standard header `<iso646.h>`.